# Setup nginx to serve static html web pages based on url

Tags: nginx

Id like to serve to different websites based on url user enter.
For example if user will go to

`my-domain.pl/` the content will be served from **desktop** folder

`my-domain.pl/desktop`  the content will be served from **desktop** folder

`my-domain.pl/mobile`  the content will be served from **mobile** folder

```
 root
  |
  |---mobile
  |      |--- assets
  |              |---js,css,img
  |      
  |---desktop
         |--- assets
                 |---js,css,img
```

I tried that in nginx setup file:

```
 server {

    root /desktop

    location /mobile {
        root /mobile
    }    

    location /desktop{
        root /desktop
    }    

 }
```

but it works only for `/` path, remaining paths return `404`

I tried to add `try_files $uri index.html` but it seems that it returns index.html files for all request for this location e.g. it returns index.html file instead javascript too.

I am absolutely new in setting up nginx so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of the `alias` directive instead of `root`: see [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).

```
server {

    root /;

    location /desktop {
    }    

    location /mobile {
        alias /mobile;
    }    
 }
```

(don't forget trailing semicolons)

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid specifying `root` inside `location` blocks (cf. [nginx pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block)).

Have you tried the following:

- have only one `root`
- use `rewrite` to serve `/desktop` by default

The config would look like:

```
server {

  root /;

  ## this should take care of the redirect to /desktop by default:
  location = / {
    rewrite ^ /desktop/ redirect;
  }
  ## this one below probably doesn't work:
  # rewrite ^/$ /desktop/;

}
```

P.S. I have no access to a machine with nginx right now so I'm not able to check the `rewrite` syntax. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17745810/1006854).