# Moving Cakephp 3.x application into nginx subfolder

Tags: cakephp, nginx, cakephp-3.0

#### System

- **nginx** on Ubuntu
- **CakePhp 3.4.6**

#### Problem

I'm trying to move a CakePhp application into a subfolder on the webserver.

1. Let's say the subfolder is called **/project**
2. and root webserver directory is under **/var/www/html/**

I tried something like this in the nginx default (without any success):

```
location /project {
        alias /var/www/html/project/webroot;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /project/webroot/index.php;
}
```

The subfolder url-suffix is always interpreted as a controller.

I am guessing that I need to set specific values in the app.php file, so cakephp knows that the url has a prefix but I haven't found a value combination that works yet.

Anybody has guidance here?

Comment: Not an nginx expert myself, but have you tried something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/17738677/2403513 yet? It might be helpful to add the nginx tag to attract answers from that community.

Comment: I think the only issue is that cakephp doesn't recongnize der path prefix as subfolder. I'm sure I need to set specific value in the app.php, but haven't found a combination that works. I tried to fiddle with nginx (also the link you shared) but it's not leading to anything hence it seems to be and CPHP issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a combination of app.php and nginx rewrite rule:

1. `config.php/app.php`

   `'base' => '/project'`
2. `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

`

```
location /project {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    # prevent recursion
    if ($request_uri ~ /webroot/index.php) {
        break;
    }

    rewrite ^/project$ /project/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/project/webroot/(.*) /project/webroot/index.php last;
    rewrite ^/project/(.*)$ /project/webroot/$1 last;
}
```

`

Comment: Good solution, but let me do some nitpicking. In step 1, do not modify app.php. Instead, add the following blob to config/app_local.php: `  'App' => [ 'base' => '/project',],`.